# Storyboards - Tab Views - Segue / Modal Views

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Using storyboards and tabviews for my app. I do use one Storyboard Segue / Modal to show a quick reference view, then a button back to the tabview where it came from. When it comes back, the tabview is gone (bottom of the screen). Is there a way to have it Segue come back without loosing the the tabs at the bottom, or is there a better way to have a "pop-up" screen for the quick reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you going back to the table view?

Comment: With the same Segue / Modal link

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't go "backwards" to a controller you've come from using a segue, unless you use an unwind segue. When you do that, you're not really going back, you're creating a new instance of that controller. So, either use an unwind segue or go back using code (dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion).